# Malware Defense Shows Up in PlayOn Settings/Logs Although System Has Been Thoroughly Cleaned

Tags: anti-virus, malware, media-server

I was hit really hard by some nasty malware:  Malware Defense.  I was doing something I should not have been doing when I got it (surfing Pirate Bay for TV shows).  It locked up my system and I had to reboot in safe mode.  I was able to shut down the process and remove it using a malware killer tool.

I then installed, after my machine was cleaned up a bit, Clamwin, Malwarebytes, and another AV tool.  I cleaned the heck out of my system.

Simultaneously, while this was going on, I was having trouble with my media-server, PlayOn.  This tool is great, but has some bugs.  One in particular is that it will not function well with AV software running.  I found a way to allow the new AV software to run while using PlayOn, but it still says I have Malware Defense on.  Firstly, Malware Defense is long gone.  I cleaned all remnants from my registry and scoured my system with the above tools multiple times.

PlayOn is getting some information that I have this crap installed on my system, but it's not.  The system runs OK, but not optimally.  I have a feeling it is causing my streaming to be interrupted sometimes.  How is it that I can't even find Malware Defense on my system if I tried but yet somehow PlayOn is getting a finger print of it somewhere?  I have gone back and forth with MediaMall to no avail.  I kind of just gave up, because the streaming works OK.

BTW, I also uninstalled/reinstalled PlayOn several times, reverted back to previous versions, etc.  The only thing I haven't done is reformat my disk and reinstall Windows.  I really don't want to do this if there is another way to remove this little print.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried installing the media server on another partition and running it from there?

Comment: I actually do have PlayOn installed on the same machine but on the second drive on the Windows XP 64-bit OS.  It works great with no trace of Malware Defense.  So I know the finger print is on the drive with the XP installation.  I will try to install on another partition as you suggested and see if this works.  Thanks.